# Как правильно обезопасить информацию пользователя в vk mini apps

Tags: php, vk-mini-apps

Подскажите как правильно обезопасить информацию пользователя. В планах хранить настройки для каждого пользователя в БД, когда пользователь заходит в приложение, сам сайт загружается через ifram и в ссылке есть параметр `vk_user_id` по которому я хотел определять, кто вошел в приложение, принимать этот параметр на сервере и проверять его в БД и отдавать настройки.
Проблема в том, что через исходный код страницы, можно изменить ссылку в iframe, указать любое другое значение в параметр `vk_user_id` и уже отправляется запрос, что якобы в приложение зашел другой пользователь, которого ид указал в урл, как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы в [документации вк](https://vk.com/dev/vk_apps_launch_params?f=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20PHP)

Получается по мимо параметра `vk_user_id` передается еще `sign`, который содержит в себе id пользователя + защищённый ключ(Лежит в настройках приложения) в кодировке `base64`.
На стороне сервера получаем id и sign пользователя, защищённый ключ из настроек приложение держим в переменной, отправляем полученный id и имеющийся ключ в base64, полученный результат сверяем с sign.

Теперь при подмене `vk_user_id` получаем `fail`

```
    $url = "https://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
    $client_secret = 'ххх'; //Защищённый ключ из настроек вашего приложения

    $query_params = [];
    parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $query_params); // Получаем query-параметры из URL

    $sign_params = [];
    foreach ($query_params as $name => $value) {
        if (strpos($name, 'vk_') !== 0) { // Получаем только vk параметры из query
          continue;
        }
        $sign_params[$name] = $value;
    }

    ksort($sign_params); // Сортируем массив по ключам
    $sign_params_query = http_build_query($sign_params); // Формируем строку вида "param_name1=value&param_name2=value"
    $sign = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $sign_params_query, $client_secret, true)), '+/', '-_'), '='); // Получаем хеш-код от строки, используя защищеный ключ приложения. Генерация на основе метода HMAC.

    $status = $sign === $query_params['sign']; // Сравниваем полученную подпись со значением параметра 'sign'

    echo ($status ? 'ok' : 'fail')."\n";
```